# Bash Script to convert text file which consists with millions of lines to mongodb insert query

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a requirement to convert a text file to below mentioned format.It consists with millions of lines of data.The format of text as below.

```
    256456123
    456852159
    789123744
    .........
```

This is the format i need after converting.The intention is to create below mongodb insert query.

```
     db.database_name.insert([
     {
       "number":"256456123"
     },
     { "number":"456852159"
     },
     { "number":"789123744"
     }
     ]);
```

How can I do this using bash script?

Comment: **Either** [A] (1) Loop over the lines in your input file and (2) for each line print the JSON part, **or** [B] (1) use a suitable `sed` command which replaces eich line by `{ "number": line },`, which will cause a superfluous comma after the last line, and then (2) remove that final comma using the command `head`.

Comment: Obligatory `jq` one-liner: `jq -cR '{ "number": . }' infile`

Comment: how can we save the output to external file using jq ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're looking for an array of objects, since your sample output isn't valid JSON as is.

Something like

```sh
sed -e '1s/.*/[{"number":"&"}/' \
    -e '2,$s/.*/,{"number":"&"}/' \
    -e '$s/$/]/' input.txt > output.json
```

will put brackets around it all, and by putting a comma *before* each object on all lines but the first, avoid issues with an extra trailing comma.